# Screenshot secure desktop

Tags: c#, screenshot

I am working with screen sharing project.I am capturing desktop screen using below function.it works fine. But whenever [secure desktop prompting for elevation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-switch-to-the-secure-desktop-when-prompting-for-elevation).it returns black/empty image.

But when i [turn off secured desktop](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-turn-off-the-secure-desktop-in-windows-7) from local security policy.It works fine.

Is there any way to capture secure desktop without disabling Local Security Policy.

```
static Bitmap CaptureDesktop()
{
    SIZE size;
    Bitmap printscreen = null;

    size.cx = Win32Stuff.GetSystemMetrics
                     (Win32Stuff.SM_CXSCREEN);

    size.cy = Win32Stuff.GetSystemMetrics
              (Win32Stuff.SM_CYSCREEN);

    int width = size.cx; int height = size.cy;

    IntPtr hWnd = Win32Stuff.GetDesktopWindow();
    IntPtr hDC = Win32Stuff.GetDC(hWnd);
    if (hDC != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        IntPtr hMemDC = GDIStuff.CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
        if (hMemDC != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            IntPtr m_HBitmap = GDIStuff.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, width, height);
            if (m_HBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                IntPtr hOld = (IntPtr)GDIStuff.SelectObject(hMemDC, m_HBitmap);
                GDIStuff.BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, width, height, hDC, 0, 0, GDIStuff.SRCCOPY);
                GDIStuff.SelectObject(hMemDC, hOld);
                GDIStuff.DeleteDC(hMemDC);
                printscreen = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(m_HBitmap);
                GDIStuff.DeleteObject(m_HBitmap);
            }
        }
    }
    Win32Stuff.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);

    return printscreen;
}
```

**Edit**:

1. Exe Installed in Secured location
2. Exe is digitally signed

Comment: This is not a solution but recommendation. I tried the same way for capturing the screen with the input audio and create a mpeg file. First problem is this way capturing the screen is a bit slow and consuming too much cpu. Second, there are limitations what can be grabbed from the video memory this way. That time, I searched the internet about screen capturing and found that successful applications hook the drawing APIs of Windows for this purpose. Checking the screen/window capture plugin of OBS may help. https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/tree/master/plugins/win-capture

Comment: Thanks @NthDeveloper i will check that

Comment: I hope this link might help : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/capture-desktop-activities-as-a-movie/

Comment: @KamalaHB thanks for link.it will not work out for me as its video recording.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to get the screen contents of the Secure Desktop, your application needs to fulfill some special criteria:

- it must run under the SYSTEM account, not the logged-on user account
- it must run on the Winlogon desktop, not on the user desktop
- it should run as a service

To test it, you could e.g. use the [SysInternals PsExec tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to run your application in that mode:

```
PsExec /h /x /d /s "path_to\your_application.exe"
```

The `/x` and `/s` switches are important: they run the process under the SYSTEM account and on the Winlogon desktop.

If you want to avoid using third-party tools, you need to create your own Windows service which will perform the screen captures of the Secure Desktop.

There is no source code of `PsExec` available, but you can look at the `PAExec` tool's [source code](https://github.com/poweradminllc/PAExec) - it's an open source alternative.

Comment: I tried but very difficult to implement.I wonder how team viewer do this all without installing software in Machine.

Comment: You don't need to install anything. You can directly run your service just as `PsExec` does. There is no source code of `PsExec` available, but you can look at the [`PAExec` tool source code](https://github.com/poweradminllc/PAExec) - it's an open source alternative.

Comment: Thanks it help me alot

Comment: pls check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101802/c-sharp-screenshot-winlogon-as-well-as-user-desktop. if you have any idea ?